# How to restrict to view .asmx methods definition by url

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

My .asmx web services is accessible to outside. So anybody can see methods by access url. Is there anyway to hide those methods to see outside, but accessible to project?

suggestions please.

Comment: Why is it a problem? If your service call is invisible, how are you planning on your clients connecting to it? What matters is that it's secured (ie. use authentication) not that it's invisible. But what are you trying to do?

Comment: or may be host it on a private port ....

Comment: I believe he is asking how to hide the method names from view, not make the service inaccessible.

As Arindam Nayak mentioned below, add the setting to hide documentation into your webconfig in the environments you don't want to expose this information to.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Hide-Method-Description-and-Documentation-of-ASP.Net-ASMX-Web-Services-when-browsed.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To disable the documentation protocol ( hide The operations that are supported , The parameters that each operation accepts, The type of data that should be passed in those parameters )  for Web services follow any one of these 2 steps

1. add this in ur web.config

`<system.web>
    <webServices>
             <wsdlHelpGenerator href="helpPage.aspx"></wsdlHelpGenerator> 
    </webServices>
</system.web>`

2. Use following in web.config

> ```
> <system.web>
> <webServices>
>     <protocols>
>          <remove name="HttpPost" />
>          <remove name="HttpGet" />
>         <remove name="Documentation"/> 
>     </protocols>
> </webServices>
> </system.web>
> ```

SOURCE - http://forums.asp.net/t/1185735.aspx